# How to highlight missing comma in lua files?

Tags: highlight, lua

I often forget the comma between embedded table entries in lua code.

```lua
t = {
    a = { "str" },
    b = {
      {
        "str3",
        v = 1, 
      }  <<-- missing comma
      {
        ime_state,
        color = {fg = 'black', bg = '#f46868'}
      },
      ...
    },
    c = { "str1", "str2" },
},
```

Is there a way in vim / neovim to highlight such errors?

Comment: There is, but it's complicated and error-prone. I suggest you use an LSP server for Lua. It'll tell you all the errors in the file, not just missing comma. Check this repository: [nvim-lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig).

Comment: After installing the language server: `scoop install lua-language-server` and followed the instructions in `help: server_configurations` under **sumneko_lua** it works well.

Comment: @Mattia72 please answer in the Answer section, not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in `help: lspconfig-server-configurations` under **sumneko_lua**

Now I see every syntax error, while I type:

[image]